# Blender 3 - Make Shadow Catcher pass transparent instead of white

Tags: compositing-nodes, shadowcatcher

The new shadow catcher is awesome. However the rendered pass has a white background (in the viewport it works as expected).
How can I get a pass with just shadow data, transparency and no white?

Edit: `Film -> Transparent` also does not work.

Edit: [Here is the .blend  file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zSVTslbT4wzPukez_rrR2SXiCMwxAm4/view?usp=sharing)

I found a workaround, which works, but not perfectly:
Masking the shadow with a black and white inverted version of itself. This does however introduce artefacts.

[image: image pass]
[image: shadow catcher pass]

Comment: Render setting > Film >Transparent doesn't work?

Comment: @MikoCG Sadly no :/

Comment: Can you share this file with us?

Comment: @MikoCG I added the file in the question :)

Comment: You have to multiply the *shadow catcher* pass on top of your background, see the actual release notes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Shadow_Catcher

Comment: But I dont want to have a background from the render. I want to add the image with a transparent shadow on for example a website or other graphics in Photoshop
Or do you mean that I just multiply it with composite? I try that out. Edit: Does not work :/

Comment: Hello, I was about to ask this same very question here and ran into your post.  I am having the exact same problem.  Previous versions of Blender seem to do it just fine, but Blender 3.0 seems to render ShadowCatcher differently.  Even if I export as OpenEXR to photoshop, the ShadowCatcher render layer is still black and white!  No transparency.  Hoping this question gets answered.

Answer (score 6):

You can reroute any color chanel into alpha chanel. In the example below "Gamma" node manage shadow transparency:

[image]

Also it is possible to create shadow of any color:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Nice. Could you please add more details about why you used the Invert Node, and separated the Blue channel? Just wanna learn how this stuff works :)). Thanks.

Comment: @JachymMichal Full transparent RGBA: R=0, G=0, B=0, A=100. Black RGBA: R=0, G=0, B=0, A=0. White RGBA: R=100, G=100, B=100, A=0. That is why i have to invert white into black. If I will not use Invert Node there will be alpha at the place of shadow. Nevermind what color channel will be set to alpha. It could be Red or Green instead of Blue. Because all color channels are identical when they are parts of black or white or grayscale color.

Comment: Hey thanks for the details, much appreciated ;)

Comment: The shadow loses all colour information and turns black and white then.
This technique however  does not introduce artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for **Set Alpha** node, probably ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: The shadow also looses all coulor information with that technique :/
However, plugging the shadow catcher pass into the "Set Alpha" - Image parameter does the trick I think. Have not tested it well though. Can you edit your answer to include that?

Comment: Yes, color is lost due running data into Alpha channel. Yes, you can plug Shadow Catcher into Image socket, but you will never get naturally looking result (shadow doesn't interact with bg colour). With Set Alpha node you will lose also Emission/Indirect data, if any. Proper compositing is with Math > Multiply node ... [see here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.0/Cycles#Shadow_Catcher) ... but without transparency. OpenEXR can store all those data for later proper compositing. If you are OK with just a fake for PNG file use my A, adjust color in Set Alpha.