# Compositing shadow catcher + no background

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency

I recently finished a big batch of renders I composed in Blender.  Now the client wants the renders with transparent background. I thought It will be as easy as just changing the white color multiplied by the shadow catcher using a mix node to transparent. I modified the alpha of the white expecting to get no color behind my shadows, but that does not do the trick. I also tried to use a transparent png instead of a color in my mix node. That did not work either.
[image]

This is a mockup scene (I can not share the original file, but the principle is the same). As you can see I am able to change any color I want for the background, but I can not find the way to change that purple color into "no color" to get what I am aiming for *The render with shadows and no background.*

Of course, I could render a png with transparent background from the beginning and bypass the compositor. But I did use the compositor to tweak things with cryptomattes and decrease the shadow intensity.

Is there any way to output in the compositor the shadow with a transparent background instead of a fill color?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for **Set Alpha** node, probably?

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice, didn't know such node existed :) [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245413/78972) could've used your help :))

Comment: This is a great contribution! Thank you! @vklidu The only issue I see here is that by using that node then the shadows became driven by one color while the shadow catcher have way more color details from bouncing objects around it.

Comment: @BrunoSuraski For colour thing, see my comment in duplication link ...

Comment: @vklidu I see, so I can only get the "accurate" shadow if I know the color and add it in the composition. But I can not have a transparent background with the correct shadow.

Comment: Yes :) Correct shadow data with transparency are stored only in OpenEXR passes (uncropped data can be mixed back with a new bg color properly). Files like PNG cant store emissive data and any pixel of shadow and indirect light is always contaminated by original BG colour. Even rendered on white bg the shadow pixels are contaminated by white, shadow is greyish and will never look natural on pink bg. To blend BW shadow catcher with bg, set it a bit grey so the shadow became a bit transparent (so result is contaminated by new bg color) or adjust color in Set Alpha node.