# fire with transparency

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, fire, .exr

i tried following [this](https://youtu.be/rzATaYyCf9Q) tutorial on realistic fire in blender, and all went very good up until the rendering. Blender apparently renders it with no problems at all

[image: fire]

but once I save the file it simply does not show the fire at all:

[image: no fire]

I also tried rendering it with EXR filetype, but it also doesn't "render" the fire. But rendering it with JPEG or PNG without transparency it works just fine:

[image: workin]

[image]

Comment: Fire is a part of emissive data so it is there in EXR, but visible only. if compositor over  non transparent pixels. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214

Comment: ... or another way https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271902/2214 that produce semitransparent pixels, but that will never result in a proper composit.