# Compositing not saving all layers

Tags: rendering

So I have done a compositing, which one layer consists of my **objects** and the second one of my **lights**.

After compositing and rendering, the result looks like this:
[image]

But when I save to my computer, it looks like this:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Search for saving emissive data over transparent ore semitransparent ... basically - lights are there if you save as EXR format.

Comment: @vklidu even with EXR you won't save the bloom effect, you need to use some mask tricks in the Compositor or in the Video Sequencer

Comment: @moonboots yes you can save bloom https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214 (if there isn't a change from that time) ... you can't see it as it is (if you mean that), but the emissive data are saved in file. To make them visible on transparent/semitransparent pixels is another topic :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271902/2214 or here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165275/2214

Comment: @HaruShiba ... to answer (or close as duplicate) your Q we need to know more about your file format, expectation of how result should looks like or how do you plan to work (your next steps) with these renders.

Comment: @vklidu OK i'll try to understand   ;)